# Why do I keep getting an Apple Mach-O Linker Error Using the Youtube API in GDATA

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api, gdata

Hi I keep trying to build my project, but I keep getting 4 errors.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I definitely added the GData code correctly, and I did add the libxml2.dylib in my build phases. & in my other linker flags I have -OBjC, -lxml2, -all_load. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're GData library is only compiling for arm7 and you might be trying to support arm6, try going into your architectures section of your GdataTouchStaticLib and add "armv6" to the release/debug targets.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I've however chosen to not use the GDATA framework anymore and have found a better way of doing what I wanted to do without GData. Since your answer is much more detailed I will go ahead and make it the correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance import VideosTableViewController.**m** instead of **.h** somewhere in your code?